# how do i add to a csv file from a different function in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

Am fairly new to programming and am needing a way to add input data from one function and have it add into a csv file

```
    def songlists():
        with open('songs.csv') as csvfile:
            songs = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            x = [row for row in songs]
            return x

    def menu(x):
print("Songs to Learn 1.0 - ")
songlists()
print(len(x), "songs in list")
print("""Menu :
L - List songs
A - Add new song
C - Complete a song
Q - Quit""")
menuChoice = str(input('>>>'))
while menuChoice != "q":
    if menuChoice == "l":
        songlists()
        i = 0
        for row in x:
            name, artist, year, learnt = row
            print(str(i),'.', learnt, name, artist, "(", year, ")")
            i += 1
    elif menuChoice == "a":
        songlists()
        #want to be able to add to the csv file from here and be able to add the new name artists and year etc
        #print("??")
    elif menuChoice == "c":
        print("???")
    else:
        print("Invalid choice, Choose again")
    print("""Menu :
    L - List songs
    A - Add new song
    C - Complete a song
    Q - Quit""")
    menuChoice = str(input('>>>'))
```

what i would like to do is on the input of "a" by the user in function menu() it prompts them to add the name and artist etc and then add it to the csv file which is opened in the songlist function.
sorry if this question is badly formatted.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to the specifics of csv.reader but using the standard open("text.csv") you'd need to add the parameter 'a' (i.e. open(text.csv, 'a').write(new_song, ",", something_else, "\n") so as to open it in append mode, instead of the default read (or explicitly 'r') mode.  Be careful not to use 'w' for write as this will wipe the file clean before writing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small piece of code that should help you to solve you problem. This is not perfect because I would use a class instead of returning 3 parameters but I think it is a good start and we can improve it later:

```
import csv

def getSong():
    name = raw_input("Artist's name: ")
    song = raw_input("Song's name: ")
    year = raw_input("Year: ")

    return name, song, year

def save(filename, name, song, year):
    with open(filename, 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow([name, song, year])

(name, song, year) = getSong()

save("output.csv", name, song, year)
```

HTH